# Editor visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor, tabs, space

I have this annoying problem. I've used some kind of key combination and now my spaces are dots my tabs are arrows etc.
does anyone know how to turn this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit->Advanced->Show Whitespace.

Comment: Normally mapped to control-R control-W.